# Spring Cloud Stream migration

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-messaging

I've noticed that @Output -> @StreamListener approach has been deprecated and totally rewritten, to be used with Supplier/Consumer approach. It's said that all functionalities has been preserved in new approach, so I'm looking for a good article/blogpost, which will help me to migrate. For example I see that there are different dependencies (pom.xml needs to be changed), binding to for example RabbitMQ needs t be configured differently etc. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is
https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/14/spring-cloud-stream-demystified-and-simplified
and then this although it touches on reactive part which you may not need
https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/17/spring-cloud-stream-functional-and-reactive
And then all our samples have been migrated to functional - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples And of course reference docs have all been updatd with all new code snippets and samples

Comment: Those two articles only scratches the surface. I'll dig through examples (maaany of them) but there's no migration guide? For example, how to migrate "condition"?
I simple need to send message from one microservice to another. Can you recommend one example of such use case?

Comment: RoutingFunction, there is a section in the reference manual

Comment: Honestly I found RoutingFunction quick complex to understand and apply to real life situation when I basically use to filter message by its type. StreamListener is behind the scenes a single Sink split in multiple methods that are filtering the message by certain criteria. I would implement such filters programmatically in the component holding `@Bean public Consumer<T> funName`

Comment: @Rogerio Ramos I am not sure what do your mean by "complex", "apply to real life situation" etc. . .. Without concrete examples it's an empty, meaningless statement, so please refrain from it

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky using the imperative style (StreamListener) it was simple to filter messages by one of its headers or payload fields, but in the example a boolean unary filter was used executing `even` or `odd` function which does not represent real life usage as asked here https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/17/spring-cloud-stream-functional-and-reactive#comment-5551299810. Also using `StreamBridge` is way intuitive compared to `Supplier<T>` do you have something else than String transformation for Producer examples?

Comment: @Rogerio Ramos Yes, it is even easier and far more dynamic to do routing bu headers with property (e.g.,  `spring.cloud.function.routing-expression=headers['type']`). And then there is `MessageRoutingCallback` if routing/filtering logic is too complex - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/3.1.6/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_function_routing_and_filtering